# Updating ImageView Native UI Component From Native Code by Id

Tags: android, react-native

I'm working with a third-party thermal imaging camera, and I'm trying to stream the preview from the camera in real-time. I'm able to render the ImageView, and I can see that my images are being retrieved successfully by logging the raw image buffer. However, when I try to update the view on the UI thread, I can't find the view by Id from the current activity, so I can update the ImageView bitmap.

My first approach was to use the device event emitter to emit base64 encoded representations of the images to react native, but that would cause freezing, etc., so I gave up on that approach.

Now, I'm creating an ImageView using the SimpleViewManager and assigning an id. Then, in my listener (created as Native module) that is receiving the image stream, I'm attempting to set the image bitmap of that ImageView by finding it by id from the current activity. However, I can't find the view by id (it's always null).

This is a part of my class extending ReactContextBaseJavaModule and is registered as a native module. The context is the activity retrieved by calling `getCurrentActivity()`.

```java
    @Override
    public void accept(ThermalImage thermalImage) {
        try {
            final Bitmap bmp = BitmapAndroid.createBitmap(thermalImage.getImage()).getBitMap();
            final Activity activity = (Activity) context;
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Running on ui thread!!");
                    final ImageView imageView = activity.findViewById(R.id.thermal_image);
                    if (imageView != null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "IMAGE VIEW NOT NULL");
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    }
                }
            });
            Log.e(TAG, "Image Received");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

ViewManager that is registered as a Native UI Module

```java
public class ThermalImageViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<ReactImageView> {

    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "RCTThermalImageView";

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    protected ReactImageView createViewInstance(@Nonnull ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        final ReactImageView imageView = new ReactImageView(reactContext, Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder(), null, null);
        imageView.setId(R.id.thermal_image);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

This is the react code that renders the view and then starts the stream.

```
    onComponentDidMount() {
      ThermalImageCapture.startStream();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', height: '100%', backgroundColor: "#231F20"}}>
              <Button onPress={this.handleClick}><Text>Camera</Text></Button>
              <ThermalImageView style={{width: 500, height: 500, backgroundColor: "white"}}></ThermalImageView>
            </View>
          );
    }
```

I think I should be able to access the view by id in this instance, but that doesn't appear to be the case. Any better approaches would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that comes across this, I figured out a way to do this. The key is using the AddUIBlockMethod to get the ImageView by tag and then pass the view along to my listener setting the bitmap.

Example:

```java
    @ReactMethod
    public void startStream(final int tag) {
        context.getNativeModule(UIManagerModule.class).addUIBlock(new UIBlock() {
            @Override
            public void execute(NativeViewHierarchyManager nativeViewHierarchyManager) {
                final ReactImageView imageView = (ReactImageView) nativeViewHierarchyManager.resolveView(tag);
                if (imageView != null) {
                    streamListener = configureListener(context, imageView);
                    streamListener.start();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

```
    componentDidMount() {
      startStream(findNodeHandle(this.imageView));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      stopStream();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', height: '100%', backgroundColor: "#231F20"}}>
              <Button onPress={this.handleClick}><Text>Camera</Text></Button>
              <Image
                ref={ref => this.imageView = ref}
                style={{width: 500, height: 500}}/>
            </View>
          );
    }
```